# How check naming convention for logger variables in scala with scalastyle?

Tags: scala, logging, scalastyle

Suppose I need to ensure that all loggers in my scala code are named `log` only, not `LOGGER`, `LOG` or `logger`. So for this style checking I need to define a `Logger` (for slf4j or log4j) and when style checker detects a variable with this type it check name.

I see [org.scalastyle.scalariform.FieldNamesChecker](http://www.scalastyle.org/rules-0.7.0.html#org_scalastyle_scalariform_FieldNamesChecker), but do not see any type checkers, so is it possible to do that with [scalastyle](http://www.scalastyle.org/rules-0.7.0.html) rules?

Answer (score 0):

Scalastyle only has access to the information in the file, so you might not have the type available.

The best solution is probably to use a Regex. Pretty much all of our loggers have the form:

```
private val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass)
```

so you could define a `RegexChecker` with an appropriate regex for your convention. You won't get all of the cases, but you'd probably get most of them.